# Decoding tx data from view call in Golang

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, golang

I have a view call in my Solidity code  that looks like this:

```
function call1 (address[] calldata targets) external view returns(Return[] memory returnData)
```

And the struct from the array which is returned looks like this:

```
struct Return {
    bool success;
    address addr;
    bytes data;
}
```

My goal is to decode the function call results of this function in Golang. So far I could log the results partially with this code:

```
res, err := client.CallContract(context.Background(), callMsg, nil)
outputDataList := make([]interface{}, 10)
outputDataList, err = contractABI.Unpack("call1", res)
fmt.Println(outputDataList[0].(interface{}))
```

I could log the `bool` and `address` from the struct, however the bytes variable is still not encoded.

```
[{true 0x8840c6252e2e86e545defb6da98b2a0e26d8c1ba[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 24 75 122 0 63 109 85 204 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 15 215 247 135 154 188 2 164 101 11 198 216 164 41 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 100 139 110 44]} {true 0x8840c6252e2e86e545defb6da98b2a0e26d8c1ba[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 24 75 122 0 63 109 85 204 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 15 215 247 135 154 188 2 164 101 11 198 216 164 41 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 100 139 110 44]}]
```

My question is that how should I continue the decode process of this? I would like to have the results in an array of structs that have the same structure as the Solidity struct. What would be the most elegant way to do it? I am also no sure that using an array (`outputDataList`) is the best option or another solution should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Golang, the Go Ethereum library provides the `abi` package which has methods to unpack the transaction data. However, because the `bytes` data type in Solidity is dynamic, it needs to be decoded differently than fixed-size types like `bool` and `address`.

You are currently using the `Unpack` method which can handle the `bool` and `address` types but is not handling the `bytes` type correctly. To handle the bytes type, you would need to manually parse it.

Here's an example:

```go
package main

import (
    "log"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
)

type Return struct {
    Success bool
    Addr    common.Address
    Data    []byte
}

func main() {
    parsedABI, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(contractABI))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to parse contract ABI: %v", err)
    }

    data, err := parsedABI.Pack("call1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to pack data for call1: %v", err)
    }

    values := make([]interface{}, 0)
    if err := parsedABI.UnpackIntoInterface(&values, "call1", data); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to unpack data: %v", err)
    }

    outputDataList := make([]Return, len(values))
    for i, v := range values {
        val, ok := v.([]interface{})
        if !ok {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to convert to interface slice")
        }

        outputDataList[i] = Return{
            Success: val[0].(*big.Int).Cmp(big.NewInt(1)) == 0,
            Addr:    common.HexToAddress(val[1].(string)),
            Data:    val[2].([]byte),
        }
    }

    log.Println(outputDataList)
}
```

This code creates a Go struct that mirrors the Solidity struct and then unpacks the values into it. The `bytes` data type is converted to a byte slice (`[]byte`) in Go. Note that this is just a basic example, and you might need to modify it based on your specific needs, especially the part that deals with the conversion of data types.

Please replace `contractABI` with the ABI of your contract and ensure that the function and field names match your contract's. If the `UnpackIntoInterface` function doesn't work as expected, you might need to do more manual decoding, especially for the `bytes` field. You can reference the Solidity ABI specification for how the data is encoded and decoded.